# Calculate normals for non-manifold mesh

Tags: light, faces, normals, unity

I'm currently playing around with unity and tried to create a room in blender and import it to unity. The room is a non-manifold mesh (on purpose) - because nobody is going to see that room from the outside and I wanted to save polygons.

The render result looks nice in blender, but in unity the room looks pretty ugly and I realized that the normals are wrong (if i recalculate normals in unity it looks OK)

I tried to recalculate the normals in blender but it started to flip around faces and calculated the wrong normals (for flipped faces).

Now my question: Is there a way to recalculate normals without blender trying to "fix" (flip) some faces or is blender not designed to work with non-manifold meshes (which are pretty usefull in games)

Comment: that is the nature of non-manifold geometry, blender has no chance to figure out wich way your normal is supposed to point without proper closed volumes. You'll need to flip the faces by hand or use clean topology.

Comment: I am flipping them by hand but blender calculates wrong normals. If I click recalulate normals blender is changing the faces and I know they can (at least in theory be calculated for non-manifolds becaus unity can do exactly that for the imported mesh)